# MVC3 filling DbSet from existing database (remote SQL Server)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am a new in developing MVC3 ASP.net apps. Here I am trying to upload a set of tables from an existing Database using code-first model

Here is my context

```
public class DocContext : DbContext
{
    public DocContext() : base("DocContext") { }

    public DbSet<FC>  FCs{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<FCV>  FCVs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MB> MB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MBM>  MBM { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MBA>  MBA { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Par> Pars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PC>  PCs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PCM> PCMs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();  
    } 
}
```

At the beginning of my PC controller class I say:

```
public DocContext db = new DocContext();
```

My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="DocContext"
         connectionString ="Data Source= my remote sql host; Initial Catalog=Name of the Database that hols my Tables(FC, FCV, MB, MBA, Pars, PC, PCM); Integrated Security=True";
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But the data is not uploaded into my `DbSet` so if I try to query `db.FC` there is nothing there. I can use the same connectionstring and fill up adapters with the correct data from the database so I concluded that the connection string is fine. What am I doing wrong?

I have googled my problem for many hours, in everything I found people where either using a local SQL Server or filling out one table through the remote server.

Comment: Is that remote SQL Server on your own domain?? You have `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string - so that requires the database server to be part of the same domain as your own computer is. If you have a remote SQL Server outside your domain, don't use integrated security....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it is because I can connect to the database using the same connection string inside the test method I wrote in the same application (I am able to fill out corresponding Datatables).

Comment: I tried taking out the Integrated Security, same problem.

Comment: Can you show us **how** you query the `db.FC` ?? All I see looks okay, so I'm wondering if you're just querying it in some way that doesn't work / isn't as it should be..

Comment: var param = from s in db.FC
                      select s; // When I put a break point here and try to see db.FC (or any of my tables in the watch window It gives me the "could not be evaluated" error. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, it was db.FCs I renamed my table name for this post and had a typo.

Comment: The problem is not in the connection string, it's in the SQL Security, you have to define remote connection.

Comment: IamStalker, could you please expand a little bit on what you mean? Thanks. By the way, my datasets are huge, could this problem have anything to do with the connection dropping out before it can fill out the context? If so, maybe Dbsets are not the right way of going about this and I shuold just query my database instead of wanting to work with a local copy offline.